# AWS Cost Explorer: Cost per instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi we have about hundred instances in AWS but we don't have a clue which uses what.

We'd need to be able to view costs per instance.

We've tried tags etc everything possible in settings but without any luck. Do we need to make linked account to or something to each instance? Or should we just move away from aws? Or is there some external service for this?

Comment: You can quite simply calculate the cost for any specific instance based on [the instance type and cost in your region](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand), you don't need cost explorer for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate cost using AWS Cost Calculator: https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html